# backbone: how to stringify only a set of models of a collection?

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

I'm a bit confused about the approach to my problem. I'm building a small application with backbone. Very minimal, without routing/syncing.
Basically, the user loads images, grouped by 'bannerboxes', and the 'bannerboxes' are grouped by 'groups'. In Backbone I've got a Group and a Bannerbox model, with relative collections. In frontend, the user can create n groups and for each group can create n bannerboxes. Fine. Now the problem: I don't want the user to update every single bannerbox every time. I want the user to click only one single 'save' button at the botton of the page.

That leads to the fact that not necessarily all the bannerboxes will be totally filled up with data when the user clicks 'save'. Nor all the groups just created will necessarily have a set of bannerboxes.

So I'll have to manually check the validity of the on-page data, and based on this check, send to the server only the really valid models.

I see that's not possible, for example, to pass an array of cids/ids the backbone's collection's toJSON method. So what? What could it be a good way of doing this?

Comment: You can override toJSON method to include you logic (check the validity) and return only that models which are valid.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you'll use the .save method to send the data to the server. Then the validate method should meet your needs.

http://backbonejs.org/#Model-validate

*This method is left undefined and you're encouraged to override it with any custom validation logic you have that can be performed in JavaScript. By default save checks validate before setting any attributes but you may also tell set to validate the new attributes by passing {validate: true} as an option.*